# How to create a define for a single vue document?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a Vue file component structure like this

```
<template> ... </template>
<style lang = "scss" scoped> </style>
<script> </script>
```

But I need to make something like `#define SOMETHING 1;`

and this SOMETHING should be available everywhere in this vue file
so that you can do

```
$ my-scss-var: SOMETHING;
```

or

```
let myJsVar = SOMETHING;
```

or even

```
<div> SOMETHING </div>
```

but this SOMETHING should only exist within the given vue file - are there similar plugins for webpack?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is anything exactly like what you want, But maybe this will help you:

```
<template>
 <div :style="myVars">{{ SOMETHING }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
   return { SOMETHING: 'red'}
 },
 computed: {
  myVars () {
    return{
      '--text-color': this.SOMETHING,
    }
  }
 }
<script>

<style scoped>
   div{
     color: var(--text-color);
   }
</style>
```